# Is memcache working in go on appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, memcached

I have an app that tries to store small images (less than 50kB) in memcache, but each call to memcache.Set() results in an error `memcache: server error`.
I'm on the shared memcache class, so I understand there is no service guarantee, but currently I have no service at all.
Is it a temporary outage? Am I just unlucky?

Here is the piece of code creating an item and calling memcache. `ctx` is the appengine context for the request. `memkey` is my key (a string). `img_data` is a string with my data.
This code works well in the local dev environment.

```
cache_item = &memcache.Item{
    Key: memkey,
    Value: bytes.NewBufferString(img_data).Bytes(),
}
err = memcache.Set(ctx, cache_item)
if err != nil {
    ctx.Infof("Could not store image in memcache: %s", err)
}
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's still happening, file a bug, but I suspect it was just a transient problem.

Incidentally, your Value initialiser is unnecessarily complex. This would work the same:

```
cache_item = &memcache.Item{
    Key:   memkey,
    Value: []byte(img_data),
}
```